# Facebook JS SDK - "ga is undefined"

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using **Facebook JS SDK** for integrating Like buttons in my Rails App.  This sunny Monday the like buttons disappeared, and I opened Firebug to check what was going on. I found this error:

```
ga is undefined (line 25 of http://connect.facebook.net/en_US.all.js#xfbml=1)
```

So... I created an empty file not related to my Rails app, and I did something as simple as:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" font=""></fb:like>
</body>
</html>
```

And yes, the error is still there.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm getting this same error!! There are times during the day -- it seems to be working... and then all of a sudden, not working.. they must be updating something in the backend??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a ticket to Facebook, and apparently some other people were having the same problem. It seemed to be a temporary problem because now is up and running normally.  I wasn't able to find the reason, and one of the Facebook employees replied when everything was running normally, so I can't give a clear answer of what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `<div class="fb-like"></div>` instead of `<fb:like></fb:like>`

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ and refetch the example code.

It took me a while before I noticed the change in HTML code provided by Facebook.

Comment: Waldemar, you can use both. You decided to use HTML5, and I decided to use XFBML :)

Answer (score 0):

if you add `<div id="fb-root"></div>` to your page it will work again ... not sure if it's a temporary bug or a change within their API yet ... :-/

Answer (score 0):

I have fix this bug (for **sharrre**, jquery plugin) by adding this div:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

Edit: oops I haven't seen the Hellkeeper answer's :)

Answer (score -2):

Your href property is empty in the fb:like tag.

Comment: That is not the problem. By default if it is empty, it will get the current page.